# hosting two apps by nginx frontend and api

Tags: .net, angular, linux, nginx, .net-core

I'm trying to hosting my Angular app and My .net core app on nginx but I have I problem with configuration. My idea is when user will go to the page (for example enter my IP number 147.135.xxx.xxx) will be redirected to port 4200 . This is my angular app. However, my net.core application will run locally on vps and I would like it to run on localhost: 5000.

I want to also to my apps working 24 hours a day as a service that I can turn on and off and will run in the background (if it can be done), and not as applications that I have to run separately.

So far all I have done is run the .net core API, but as an external request from the site (Typing 147.135.xxx.xxx / + endpoint to api gives the data fine)

This is my config /etc/ngnix/sites/available/default file

```
server {
       listen 80;
       server_name _;
       
location / {
       proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
       }
}
```

How to configure files ?

Answer (score 0):

Create two locations, one for api and other for angular app. Let api which is in .net core, run on a port like: 8080 and angular will run on port 5000.

```
location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080; # For Api, add other headers
}

location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000; # For angular app, add other headers
}
```

Now by default your angular app will be served on port 80, and if you append the URL by /api, your .net core app will be accessible.

Let see...